# Resolve why R is not using the full colour ramp in the package tmap

Tags: r, color-ramp

I am creating a map using tmap with a quantitative variable that I wish to use for setting the polygon colours. When I set the colour ramp using a standard RColorBrewer palette or with a custom vector of colours, it is only using half of the values in the colour ramp (but I want them all!). For example, with the "RdYlGn" palette, it is only plotting from yellow to green without any reds.

Let's take the example of the `meuse` dataset (I am taking the start of this example from this answer ([Mapping several maps with the same colorscheme in tmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263309/mapping-several-maps-with-the-same-colorscheme-in-tmap/263340#263340)))

```
library(sp)
library(tmap)
library(rgeos) # for the gBuffer function in this example

data(meuse, meuse.area)       

coordinates(meuse) <- ~x + y 

meuse.area <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.area)),'1')))

proj4string(meuse)<- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
proj4string(meuse.area)<- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

#turn it into a spatial polygon for my purposes

meuse.poly=gBuffer(meuse, width=100, byid=TRUE)

tm_shape(meuse.poly)+
    tm_polygons("dist", title="dist",
         palette="RdYlGn", n=6)
```

Here's the map with this example:

[image]

But I don't get the full spectrum of colours:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `auto.palette.mapping=FALSE` in `tm_polygon()`.

```
tm_shape(meuse.poly) +
tm_polygons("dist", title="dist", palette="RdYlGn",                 
            auto.palette.mapping=FALSE, n=6)
```

[image: plot]

See the help page (argument `auto.palette.mapping`):

> **auto.palette.mapping**
>
> When diverging colour palettes are used (i.e. "RdBu") this method automatically maps colors to values such that the middle colors
>   (mostly white or yellow) are assigned to values of 0, and the two
>   sides of the color palette are assigned to negative respectively
>   positive values. When categorical color palettes are used, this method
>   stretches the palette if there are more levels than colors.